# How to disable double click event in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a quiz game and I want to disable double clicking after the users first answer. I have found lots of ways to do it by using Jquery but I want to do it in Javascript.
I have already passed click event listeners on my elements.

```
[...quizAnswers].forEach((qa, index) => qa.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
let isCorrect = event.target.innerText === data.results[round].correct_answer;

event.target.style.backgroundColor = isCorrect ? "green" : "red";
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please show where you close your click handler function.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the parameter [`once: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters) to prevent accidental multiple clicks/handling:

```js
qa.addEventListener("click", function(event) { /*...*/ }, {once: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't disable the action ?

```
[...quizAnswers].forEach(qa => qa.addEventListener("dblclick", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
));
```